# No me muestra el primer registro de mi tabla Datatables

Tags: php, mysqli, datatables

muchas gracias por sus respuestas en mis anteriores interrogantes, he avanzado muchísimo en mi aprendizaje, pero hoy me encuentro con un problema, resulta que mi tabla, que trae una información de los empleados desde la base de datos no me muestra el primer registro, solo me muestra del segundo en adelante.

La tabla que estoy usando es de Datatables, estoy programando en PHP y la base de datos en SQL con MySQLi, así que les comparto a continuación lo necesario para resolver el problema.

En el index es donde contengo la tabla, donde llamo a otro archivo que es el que realiza la consulta a la base de datos para mostrarla como yo la necesito:

```
                    <table id="table" class="table table-bordered border-success table-striped text-center">
                        <thead>
                            <hr>
                            <tr>
                                <th>ID</th>
                                <th class="w-25">Nombres</th>
                                <th>Cédula</th>
                                <th>Cargo</th>
                                <th>Nucleo</th>
                                <th>Fecha Ingreso</th>
                                <th>Estado</th>
                                <th>Acciones</th>
                            </tr>

                        </thead>
                        <tbody class="Empleados">
                            <?php include_once 'empleados.php' ?>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

El archivo donde hago la consulta y muestro la información en la tabla es el siguiente:

**Editado:**

```
<?php
include("conn.php");
$sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM clientes");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
    echo '
                    <tr>
                        <td>' . $row['id'] . '</td>
                        <td><a href="visualizar.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">' . $row['nombres'] . '</a></td>
                        <td>' . $row['cedula'] . '</td>
                        <td>';
                        if ($row['cargo'] == 1) {
                            echo '<span class="badge   text-dark">DESPACHADOR</span>';
                        } else if ($row['cargo'] == 2) {
                            echo '<span class="badge   text-dark">MONITOR</span>';
                        } else if ($row['cargo'] == 3) {
                            echo '<span class="badge   text-dark">SUPERVISOR DE APROVECHAMIENTO</span>';
                        } else if ($row['cargo'] == 4) {
                            echo '<span class="badge   text-dark">INSPECTOR DE EQUIPOS</span>';
                        } else if ($row['cargo'] == 5) {
                            echo '<span class="badge   text-dark">JEFE DE LINEA</span>';
                        } else if ($row['cargo'] == 6) {
                            echo '<span class="badge   text-dark">MOTOSIERRISTA</span>';
                        } else if ($row['cargo'] == 7) {
                            echo '<span class="badge   text-dark">ESTROBADOR</span>';
                        } else if ($row['cargo'] == 8) {
                            echo '<span class="badge   text-dark">DESCORTEZADOR</span>';
                        } else if ($row['cargo'] == 9) {
                            echo '<span class="badge   text-dark">ARRIERO</span>';
                        } else if ($row['cargo'] == 10) {
                            echo '<span class="badge   text-dark">GUADAÑADOR</span>';
                        } else if ($row['cargo'] == 11) {
                            echo '<span class="badge   text-dark">CAMINERO</span>';
                        } else if ($row['cargo'] == 12) {
                            echo '<span class="badge   text-dark">APRENDIZ SENA</span>';
                        } else if ($row['cargo'] == 13) {
                            echo '<span class="badge   text-dark">SILVICULTOR</span>';
                        } else if ($row['cargo'] == 14) {
                            echo '<span class="badge   text-dark">MECANICO</span>';
                        } else if ($row['cargo'] == 15) {
                            echo '<span class="badge   text-dark">COORDINADOR OPERATIVO</span>';
                        } else if ($row['cargo'] == 16) {
                            echo '<span class="badge   text-dark">COORDINADOR SSTAV</span>';
                        } else if ($row['cargo'] == 17) {
                            echo '<span class="badge   text-dark">GERENTE</span>';
                        } else if ($row['cargo'] == 18) {
                            echo '<span class="badge   text-dark">ASISTENTE ADMINISTRATIVO</span>';
                        } else if ($row['cargo'] == 19) {
                            echo '<span class="badge   text-dark">GESTOR FINANCIERO</span>';
                        } else if ($row['cargo'] == 20) {
                            echo '<span class="badge   text-dark">GESTOR DE SISTEMAS DE INFORMACION</span>';
                        } else if ($row['cargo'] == 21) {
                            echo '<span class="badge   text-dark">AUXILIAR SSTAV</span>';
                        } else if ($row['cargo'] == 22) {
                            echo '<span class="badge   text-dark">SUPERVISOR DE SILVICULTURA</span>';
                        } else if ($row['cargo'] == 23) {
                            echo '<span class="badge   text-dark">SUPERVISOR DE VIAS</span>';
                        } else if ($row['cargo'] == 24) {
                            echo '<span class="badge   text-dark">GESTOR ADMINISTRATIVO</span>';
                        } else if ($row['cargo'] == 25) {
                            echo '<span class="badge   text-dark">GESTOR DEL RIESGO</span>';
                        } else if ($row['cargo'] == 26) {
                            echo '<span class="badge   text-dark">COORDINADOR AMBIENTAL</span>';
                        } else if ($row['cargo'] == 27) {
                            echo '<span class="badge   text-dark">SUPERNUMERARIO</span>';
                        } else if ($row['cargo'] == 28) {
                            echo '<span class="badge   text-dark">APRENDIZ UNIVERSITARIO</span>';
                        } else if ($row['cargo'] == 29) {
                            echo '<span class="badge   text-dark">AUXILIAR ASERRIO</span>';
                        } else if ($row['cargo'] == 30) {
                            echo '<span class="badge   text-dark">MEDIDOR</span>';
                        } else if ($row['cargo'] == 31) {
                            echo '<span class="badge   text-dark">OPERADOR ASERRIO</span>';
                        } else if ($row['cargo'] == 32) {
                            echo '<span class="badge   text-dark">OPERADOR DE EVACUACION Y CARGUE</span>';
                        } else if ($row['cargo'] == 33) {
                            echo '<span class="badge   text-dark">OPERADOR DE EXTRACCION</span>';
                        } else if ($row['cargo'] == 34) {
                            echo '<span class="badge   text-dark">OPERADOR MAQUINARIA</span>';
                        } else if ($row['cargo'] == 35) {
                            echo '<span class="badge   text-dark">COORDINADOR RECURSOS HUMANOS</span>';
                        } else if ($row['cargo'] == 36) {
                            echo '<span class="badge   text-dark">COORDINADOR OPERATIVO</span>';
                        } else if ($row['cargo'] == 37) {
                            echo '<span class="badge   text-dark">RECIBIDOR DE VIAS</span>';
                        } else if ($row['cargo'] == 38) {
                            echo '<span class="badge   text-dark">MAMPOSTERO</span>';
                        } else if ($row['cargo'] == 39) {
                            echo '<span class="badge   text-dark">AUXILIAR DE MAMPOSTERIA</span>';
                        } else if ($row['cargo'] == 40) {
                            echo '<span class="badge   text-dark">INVESTIGADOR</span>';
                        }
                        echo '
                        </td>
                        <td>';
    if ($row['nucleo'] == '1') {
        echo '<span class="badge badge bg-primary">SR</span>';
    } else if ($row['nucleo'] == '2') {
        echo '<span class="badge bg-success">QD</span>';
    } else if ($row['nucleo'] == '3') {
        echo '<span class="badge bg-info">RS</span>';
    }
    echo '
                        </td>
                        <td>' . $row['fecha_ingreso'] . '</td>
                        <td>';
    if ($row['estado'] == '1') {
        echo '<span class="badge bg-success">Activo</span>';
    } else if ($row['estado'] == '2') {
        echo '<span class="badge bg-danger">Inactivo</span>';
    }
    echo '
                        </td>
                        
                        <td>
                        <a href="visualizar.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '" data-toggle="tooltip" title"Ver" class="btn btn-sm btn-sm-info"> <i class="bi bi-search"></i> </a>
                        <a href="editar.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '"  data-toggle="tooltip" title="Editar datos" class="btn btn-sm btn-success"> <i class="bi bi-pencil-fill"></i> </a>
                        <a href="ausentismo.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Ausentismo" class="btn btn-sm btn-info"> <i class="bi bi-heart-fill"></i> </a>
                        <a href="index.php?action=delete&id=' . $row['id'] . '" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Eliminar" onclick="return confirm(\'Esta seguro de borrar los datos de: ' . $row['nombres'] . '?\')" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"> <i class="bi bi-trash-fill"></i> </a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    ';
}
?>
```

La estructura de la base de datos es la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El SQL de la tabla:

**Espero esto te sirva Francisco :)**

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 5.1.0
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Servidor: 127.0.0.1
-- Tiempo de generación: 11-05-2021 a las 16:08:59
-- Versión del servidor: 10.4.18-MariaDB
-- Versión de PHP: 8.0.3

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Base de datos: `ebd`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `clientes`
--

CREATE TABLE `clientes` (
  `id` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `nombres` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `cedula` varchar(11) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `exp_ced` varchar(150) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `fecha_expedicion` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `fecha_nacimiento` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `civil` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `genero` varchar(40) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `raza` varchar(40) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `rh` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `hijos` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `acargo` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `eps` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `pensiones` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `caja` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `telefono` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `contacto` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `parentesco` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(64) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `direccion` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `nivel_educativo` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `estrato` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `tip_vivi` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `nucleo` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `cargo` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `proceso` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `estado` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `fecha_ingreso` date NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Indices de la tabla `clientes`
--
ALTER TABLE `clientes`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `cedula` (`cedula`);
ALTER TABLE `clientes` ADD FULLTEXT KEY `nombres` (`nombres`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de las tablas volcadas
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla `clientes`
--
ALTER TABLE `clientes`
  MODIFY `id` int(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=274;
COMMIT;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Y este es el script por el cual llamo a la tabla de Datatables:

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#table').DataTable();
        });
```

Entonces no se que me haría falta o si se me pasó algo por alto, pero de todas maneras muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Saludos a todos y muchas gracias.

Comment: Puedes eliminar todas esas condiciones si creas un arreglo `$cargos = [1 => 'DESPACHADOR', 'MONITOR', ... 'INVESTIGADOR'];` y luego muestras el cargo con `echo $cargos[$row['cargo]];`

Comment: En esta parte de tu código `$sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM clientes");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) {...` La sentencia  `$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);` antes de while es la que provoca que te esté saltando el primer registro. Básicamente está de mas ya que haces el fetch dentro del while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);

borra esa linea de Codigo arriba de tu while ahi ya estas realizando tu primer registro

Comment: Muchísimas gracias a los dos, ya me muestra el primer registro de la tabla, se los agradezco muchísimo.

Comment: @Triby Muchas gracias por el aporte.